# reduce if - elif-else statements from code python

Tags: python, python-re

I have the following code, in which I have too many if else statements.   I need to take image name and  split the data on "-.", based on length need to store the positional values in to a touple and return them. Is there a way to implement the same functionality with out if else statements

```
import re



def parseimage(img):
        

        strip   = img.strip('\n')
        length  = re.split("[_.]+",strip)


        #172.23.60.104_20210909144427527_XX244173_Car_01_unknown_Backward.jpg
        if(len(length)==11 ):

            country     = length[-3]
            vehicletype = length[-5]
            lane        = length[-4]
            numberplate = length[-6]
            timestamp   = length[-7]
            camera      = f"{length[-9]}-{length[-8]}"
            ADRnumber   = "unknown"

            

        #17.23.65.104_20210901082840637_XX83229_01_Car_unknown.jpg
        elif(len(length)==10 ):

            country     = length[-2]
            vehicletype = length[-3]
            lane        = length[-4]
            numberplate = length[-5]
            timestamp   = length[-6]
            camera      = f"{length[-8]}-{length[-7]}"
            ADRnumber   = "unknown" 



        #65-104_20210901082840637_XX83229_01_Car_unknown.jpg

        elif(len(length)==7 ):

            country     = length[-2]
            vehicletype = length[-3]
            camera      = length[-4]
            lane        = length[-5]
            numberplate = length[-6]
            timestamp   = length[-7]
            ADRnumber   = "unknown"


        #/20210922155240420_XX47388_62-101_CHE.jpg
        elif(len(length)==5 and ( re.search("_61-101_",img) or  re.search("_62-101_",img) ) ):

            country     = length[-2]
            camera      = length[-3]
            numberplate = length[-4]
            timestamp   = length[-5]
            lane        = "unknown"
            vehicletype = "unknown"
            ADRnumber   = "unknown"


        elif(len(length)==5):

            country     = length[-2]
            camera      = length[-5]
            numberplate = length[-3]
            timestamp   = length[-4]
            lane        = "unknown"
            vehicletype = "unknown"
            ADRnumber   = "unknown"



        #/20210922155240420_XX47388_62-101_.jpg



        elif(len(length)==4):

            camera      = length[-4]
            numberplate = length[-2]
            timestamp   = length[-3]
            country     = "unknown"
            lane        = "unknown"
            vehicletype = "unknown"
            ADRnumber   = "unknown"


        else:
            pass
            print(img)




        y = (camera,timestamp,numberplate,lane,vehicletype,country,ADRnumber)
return y
```

Comment: Is your code actually working? If so, it's a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

On first glance the substrings are distinct enough to use regular expressions to determine what type of information is contained.

1. Split file name into substrings
2. Determine datatype of substring (camera, numbersplate, ...) using `re`
3. Fill array with values

Python regular expression:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
```